# Bluehost Insert Into PHP Function Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, bluehost

Okay this sounds stupid but I can not figure this out.

I built a web application on my dev server (Plesk) with a MySQL database.

The customer wants it hosted using BlueHost. I have set everything up on the database and almost everything works perfectly normal except ONE mysql script below:

```
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
require_once('../../mysqli_connect.php');

$BranchID = $_SESSION['BranchID'];
$ManagerID = $_SESSION['ManagerID'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");

$custProd = $_POST['custProd'];
$custID = $_POST['custID'];
$prodID = $_POST['prodID'];
$units = $_POST['units'];
$prices = $_POST['price'];

foreach ($custProd as $key => $value) {
    $custProdID = $value;
    $customerID = $custID[$key];
    $productID = $prodID[$key];
    $qty = $units[$key];
    $price = $prices[$key];

    if ($qty != 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO sale (SaleDate, BranchID, ManagerID, CustomerProductID, CustomerID, ProductID, Units, UnitPrice) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);   
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "siiiiiid", $today, $BranchID, $ManagerID, $custProdID, $customerID, $productID, $qty, $price);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}
```

Again this works perfectly fine on my dev server but doesn't run on BlueHost. There is no error message coming back from the php file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Off: the point of prepared statements is that you prepare them once only and bind params / execute multiple times. Not much point doing all of these in a loop and is bad for performance. Also, there's a limit of how many statements you can have at at a time.

Comment: " I have set everything up on the database and almost everything works perfectly normal except ONE mysql script below:" PHP timeout mayby? .. You should enable "debugging" mode in PHP with `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `

Comment: I have to do them in a loop because I am sending arrays via ajax and need to create a row in the database for each value in the arrays.

Comment: You also need to use `mysqli_error($dbc)` on the query, not just error reporting. @J.Keefe Run that and what Raymond posted and see if there's anything (errors) that appear.

Comment: @J.Keefe about what you left in a comment: *"because I am sending arrays via ajax"* - That could be relevant here and there's no code to support that. The related tag for it should probably be added and the code for it, unless you feel it's irrelevant.

Comment: You'll have to ping me `@Funk` if you have something to share (with me). I probably won't be keeping this tab open for any much longer. I'd be glad to help, good luck.